# ¿como generar una lista select?

Tags: javascript, html

hola como puedo generar una lista de select con 127 opciones, ya que manualmente es ilogico realizar, tengo un codigo con document.querySelector(".testSelect"); espero no ser tan molesto con estas preguntas, desde ya muchas gracias

**

```
<select name="chls1" class="Channelst1">
    <option value="0">Ch1</option>
    <option value="1">Ch2</option>
    <option value="2">Ch3</option>
    <option value="3">Ch4</option>
    <option value="4">Ch5</option>
    <option value="5">Ch6</option>
    <option value="6">Ch7</option>
    <option value="7">Ch8</option>
    <option value="8">Ch9</option>
    <option value="9">Ch10</option>
    <option value="10">Ch11</option>
    <option value="11">Ch12</option>
    <option value="12">Ch13</option>
    <option value="13">Ch14</option>
    <option value="14">Ch15</option>
    <option value="15">Ch16</option>
    <option value="Nada">N/A</option> 
</select
```

**

Esto es lo que he intentado:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    //<![CDATA[ window.onload = function(){ 
  var campo_dia=document.querySelector('dias'); 
  for (var i=0; i < 127; i++){ 
      campo_dia.options[i]=new Option(i+1, 'v_'+(i+1)); // texto-valor 
  } 
 } //]]>
 </script>
```

Comment: Has intentado algo?

Comment: si, pero no consigo realizar <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
window.onload = function(){
var campo_dia=document.querySelector('dias');
for (var i=0; i < 127; i++){
campo_dia.options[i]=new Option(i+1, 'v_'+(i+1)); // texto-valor
}
}
 
//]]>
</script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function(){
    var $select = $(".chls1");
    for (i=1;i<=127;i++){
        $select.append($('<option></option>').val(i).html(i))
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="chls1"></select>
```

Creo que eso podria darte una idea, de igual forma te recomiendo visitar esta pregunta que buscaba exactamente lo mismo que tu, es la version de StackOverflow en ingles, pero ahi vienen muchas respuestas que podrian funcionarte. Saludos.
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43231860/how-to-create-options-from-1-to-100-in-selection-list-by-using-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

Yo veo tu código parcialmente bien, solo te haría las siguientes observaciones:

- Los elementos **`option`** serán dinámicos por lo cual no existen al momento y deben ser creados, dado eso deberás usar [**`createElement`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)
- Recupera y asigna en una variable a la etiqueta padre que en este caso sería **`select`** por medio de su clase por ejemplo
- A dicha etiqueta del paso anterior le adjuntamos las recién creadas por medio del método [**`appendChild`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)
- Por lo que veo tratas de usar el [constructor **`Option`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option) pero con la propuesta hecha notas que no hace falta
- Esta instrucción esta incorrecta: **`campo_dia=document.querySelector('dias')`** pues al método en cuestión le tienes que indicar si el selector es:

  - por medio dle nombre de la etiqueta
  - por medio de su id
  - por medio de su clase
  - etc.
- Al final usamos la misma variable contador que va aumentando en 1 por cada iteración como el valor dinámico en la propiedad **`text`** por cada **`option`** generado

Propuesta:

```html
    <select name="" id="" class="listado">
      
    </select>
    
    <script>
      let listadoElementos = document.querySelector('.listado');
      for (let contador = 1; contador<=10; contador++) {
        let elementoLista = document.createElement('option');
        elementoLista.text = contador;
        listadoElementos.appendChild(elementoLista);
      }
    </script>
```